# Как сделать проверку по БД через php?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, if

В базе таблице базы есть столбец admin (таблица называется users)
надо сделать так чтобы при логине проверялся статус admin = 1
вот код без этого:

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';

$data = $_POST;
if ( isset($data['do_login']) )
{
    $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
    if ( $user )
    {
        $admin = R::findOne('users', 'admin = 1', array($data['admin']));
        if ( $admin )
        //логин существует
        if ( password_verify($data['password'], $user->password) )
        {
            //если пароль совпадает, то нужно авторизовать пользователя
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
            echo '<div style="color:dreen;">Вы авторизованы!<br/> Можете перейти на <a href="index.php">главную</a> страницу.</div><hr>';
        }else
        {
            $errors[] = 'Неверно введен пароль!';
        }

    }else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином не найден!';
    }
    
    if ( ! empty($errors) )
    {
        //выводим ошибки авторизации
        echo '<div id="errors" style="color:red;">' .array_shift($errors). '</div><hr>';
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: непонятно зачем ты 2 раза извлекаешь данные по одному и тому же юзеру. У тебя обычных юзеров нет, только админ в бд?

Answer (score 0):

Зачем тебе второй запрос? просто сделай

```
if($user->admin == 1){}
```